# how to instruct saltstack to reload firewalld?

Tags: salt-stack, firewalld

I'm trying to configure firewalld via saltstack state file (on Centos7). I can add services just fine to permanent configuration, but that indeed goes into 'permanent' configuration, not in the running one. So, either a reload is needed or (less optional) add same services to running configuration too.

What I've used to add the service:

`public:
  firewalld.present:
    - name: public
    - services:
      - http`

That works, but just to permanent.

I've tried to add a "watch", but that won't work at all:

`firewalld:
  service.running:
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml`

Error is:

`Comment: The following requisites were not found:
   watch:
      file: /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml`

So, what can be done? How can I instruct a service reload via a state file?

Comment: "watch" is just looking for changes, it does not create missing file. Please check where you store the public.xml. Add a copy state if required.

Comment: using `onchanges` is now the preferred way instead of watch. A great explanation for both is at https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/29492#issuecomment-162967147

Comment: In SaltStack, note the default name of a state is the state id, so you can omit `- name: public` as long your id is `public`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close. You can't watch a file directly on the file system. You can only watch another Salt state.  So your example would look like this:

```
public:
  firewalld.present:
    - name: public
    - services:
      - http

firewalld:
  service.running:
    - watch:
      - firewalld: public
```

What this means is that the `service.running` state will  look for changes to the `firewalld.present` state and restart firewalld if changes did occur.

If you want a `reload` vs a complete restart, this should work:

```
public:
  firewalld.present:
    - name: public
    - services:
      - http

firewalld:
  service.running:
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - firewalld: public
```

Here's docs on the service state: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.service.html

Comment: Thanks Dave for the correct solution. One question though. You said I can't watch a file on file. system Is that limitation of salts firewalld-module?

Comment: You're welcome!

You can watch a state that's managing a file on the file system. For example if you're managing `/etc/my.cnf` with file.managed, then you can watch that state that's managing that file.

This is not specific to the firewalld module.

Comment: Don't forget to add `prune_services: False` if you want to keep other services added by other rules, if you manage your firewall from a service point of view instead than in a network point of view.